# Set session variable with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

After an authentification I want to set a session variable. The goal is to acess to the id of user on every views.

I use express and express-session.
My problem is that when I want to access to the session variable. 
I don't find if they are initialisations to do before using it. Because when I use :

```js
if(req.session.username)
```

for example, I have an error : username is not defined.

app.js :

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors=require('cors');

//var index = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');
var UsersDB=require('./routes/UsersDB');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//app.use('/', index);
//app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/Users',UsersDB);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.set({'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8;',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS', 
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-PINGOTHER', 
  'Access-Control-Max-Age': '1728000'});
 next();
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

UsersDB.js :

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Users=require('../models/Users');
var multer = require('multer');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: "fd34s@!@dfa453f3DF#$D&W", 
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: true, 
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + ".png")
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('avatar');

router.post('/login',function(req,res,next)
{
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
      // An error occurred when uploading
            return
        }
    // Everything went fine
        console.log(req.body);
        var login = req.body.username;
        var pass = req.body.password;
        
        if(req.session.username) { 
            console.log(req.session.username);
        }
        else{
            req.session.username = "toto";
        }

        const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256','YouOu').update(pass).digest('hex');
        Users.getUsersByEmail(login,function(err,rows)
        {
            if(rows == null){
                res.end("No such user");
                return;
            }
            if(rows[0].password != hash){
                res.end("Wrong pass")
                return;
            }
            else{
                res.end("Ok")
                return;
            }
        })
 
    })
});

module.exports=router;
```

Login.html :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("form[name=loginform]").submit(function(event){
 
            //disable the default form submission
            event.preventDefault();
           
            //grab all form data  
            var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
           
            $.ajax({
              url:'http://localhost:3000/Users/login',
              type: 'POST',
              data: formData,
              async: false,
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function (returndata) {
                if(returndata == "Wrong pass") {
                  alert("wrong password");
                } else if(returndata == "No such user")
                {
                  alert("no such user");
                } else {
                   alert("Welcome");
                    window.location.href="index.html"
                }
               
              }
            });
           
            return false;
        });
        

      </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see the issue is that you are initializing the session in UsersDB.js on an app module that is not going to be used. Try to initialize it in app.js instead.